# Trying to split my Ansible playbook based on the Operating System

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which needs to be run based on the operating System.
UseCase: Lets assume there is a service that is running.

On Linux we can check if it is installed and running using the 
systemctl status application.service

While command and on windows we will be using the 
sc query "ServiceName" | find "RUNNING"

Now we have to install it based on the output of the above a commands which requires us to segregate the playbook based on the OS.

Classic Example: Create a directory based on the OS

```
- name: Install QCA Agent on Linux targets
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: root
  tasks:

- name: Create Directory for Downloading Qualys Cloud Agent
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  file:
    path: /usr/q1/
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0777
    recurse: no
- name: Create Directory for Downloading Qualys Cloud Agent
  win_file:
    path: c:\q1
    state: directory
    owner: Administrator
    group: Administrator
    mode: 0777
    recurse: no
```

The playbook will alwayz be successful only if one of the condition is met and it is whether it is Windows or Unix OS. I can alwayz add a condition which will prompt based on:

```
when: ansible_distribution == 'Redhat' or ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

However what i would like to achieve is based on a condition it should trigger my playbook.yml file.

```
 name: Load a variable file based on the OS type, or a default if not found. Using free-form to specify the file.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yaml"
    - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yaml"
    - default.yaml

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html?highlight=with_first_found
```

I would like to know if there is a better example explaining the same that i could implement or if there are other ways to achieve the same.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The example you show from the Ansible docs is pretty much the best practice and is common in many playbooks (and roles for that matter) that deal with multiple OSes. If you have code that is different (instead of the variable example here), you'll be using `include_tasks` instead of `include_vars`, but the concept is the same.